# QGIS Take the attribute from the intersection

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, intersection, intersect

How to make an intersection function condition for a field calculator?I have three layers-buildings, parcels_old, parcels_new.In the layer of buildings i need to move parcel number ("n_parc" field).If there is an intersection with the layer 'parcels_old' the buildings need their number, if there is an intersection with 'parcels_new' the buildings need their number, if there is an intersection with both layers, the number from the layer 'parcels_new' is needed .
[image]

Comment: I suggest running the `intersection´ tool twice and then using the field calculator to keep the parcel numbers as you wish to.

Comment: @Erik Thank you! I did, but I wanted to automate this field for new objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple if condition to check whether there is a value for the new parcels. If not take the value of the old parcels. If there are values for the new parcels, take those.

```
if(array_length(overlay_intersects('parcels_new',"n_parc"))=0,
array_to_string(overlay_intersects('parcels_old',"n_parc")),
array_to_string(overlay_intersects('parcels_new',"n_parc"))
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Great solution!